# Is it OK to skip endpoints that I don't need or it's considered a bad practice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller

For example, User can only vote ( once a day ), see his vote, modify it and see history of votes.
How can this be implemented using REST?

***localhost/vote*** - GET - get vote history

***localhost/vote/id*** - GET - get current vote ( there can't be more than one, so having to write ID looks comically )

***localhost/vote*** - POST- create new vote ( What to do if user has already voted? )

***localhost/vote/id*** - PUT - update it ( Again ID )

Delete endpoint will be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app needs to have only the relevant endpoint that it needs.

If DELETE is not relevant, so no delete endpoint.

There is nothing bad with it.